# Xcode set viewcontroller identity iOS OpenGL

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I have a GLKit View controller which I would like to call programmatically, (change its scene) but when I go to the attributes pane, I am unable to locate the Identity property. I have attached a screenshot. am I doing something wrong? is there another way I should be calling it.

[image: XCode Attributes Pane]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch tabs at the top (Just above where it says "Simulated metrics").  I believe it's on the tab one to the left from the one you have selected in your photo.

Comment: Thank you that worked, but how would I change the scene of the GLkit view. I set the storyboard ID, but when I try to change the scene, nothing happens